# Auto start service in symbian

Tags: symbian

I have a question about symbian service. is that possible to create a service that automatically start with system ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the [Startup List Management API](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Autostart_application_on_emulator) to make an auto start application.

[How to auto start a program in symbian](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?100408-How-to-auto-start-a-program-in-S60-3rd-Edition)

Comment: thanks your answer! can i add a question more to confirm. is possible to start a service that has no gui, it only running on background. Thanks for help me.

Comment: @Thành Lê You can download example applications from the end of the article `How to autostart an application on boot up in 3rd- Startup List Management API` (http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_autostart_an_application_on_boot_up_in_3rd-_Startup_List_Management_API)

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a Qt application this is the guide you are looking for: [Autostart Qt applications at boot on Symbian devices](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Autostart_Qt_applications_at_boot_on_Symbian_devices)