# Need to write a service/daemon for Symbian/S60 in Qt

Tags: qt, service, symbian, daemon, s60

What can I use in Qt to write a service/daemon for symbian/S60 which sits in background and does some processing. It should start at boot time and remain active.
I read about QtService, but it does not exist in Qt 4.7.4. Does it has to be downloaded separately or is available in commercial version of Qt only.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236676/auto-start-service-in-symbian

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But actually I need to create a service in Qt and creating an application and putting it into startup list seems like a hack. Is there any direct way for creating a Symbian service ?

Answer (score 1):

[Qt mobility service framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-tp/service-frameworks.html) seems to have what you need.

Otherwise the standard solution for this in Symbian without Qt is to create a UI-less application and register it in the startup API mentioned in the post linked by Bill. You pull up an own Active Scheduler that will keep the application cycle running. However if you want to do also something useful with your process you've to implement a Symbian server process (local to the device, under Symbian daemon/service like behavior is called "server"). It's rather complicated stuff but you can find some examples in the SDK.